# How to show/enable logs of queries executed in spring boot data for igniterepository ? Do we have any specific property for Apache ignite repository?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, spring-data-jpa, ignite, show-sql

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Tried with above properties but those are not working out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is mandatory logging on Spring Data size, but on Ignite side there is no such thing.

One way to get that behavior is by setting `longQueryWarningTimeout` in Ignite configuration to 1, i.e 1 ms. It will get all queries which took longer than 1 ms printed with warning "Query execution is too long", effectively all of them.